# What does parent::form($form, $form_state) do?

Tags: forms, 8

I'm not able to understand what `parent::form($form, $form_state)` does in a content entity form. If I comment it out, the entity form still get rendered.

```
class AdvertiserForm extends ContentEntityForm {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function form(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);
    /** @var \Drupal\redirect\Entity\Redirect $redirect */
    $advertiser = $this->entity;
    $form['status_code'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => t('Redirect status'),

    );

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
      $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);

  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function save(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->entity->save();
    drupal_set_message(t('The redirect has been saved.'));

  }
}
```

What does `parent::form($form, $form_state)` do, exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's executing a method with the same name on its parent class. This is standard fare in any language when you're dealing with inheritance, when functionality from the base class is still (or may be in the future) required.

In this case it's the [`ContentEntityForm::form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!ContentEntityForm.php/function/ContentEntityForm%3A%3Aform/8.2.x) method that will be invoked. The fact that it doesn't appear to do/change anything is irrelevant - something might change in the future that *does* require that base class's method to be called, and by referencing it now, you're future-proofed.

Have a read up on [OO PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) if this concept is unfamiliar to you, it's one of the more basic ones, so easy to learn. There are a lot of OO concepts used in D8, learning them early on will really help you get to grips with the framework more quickly.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, `ContentEntityForm` is the name of the object, `form()` is the name of the [method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function), and `::` means that this is a static method.

Comment: It isn't a static method. When referring to a method in the documentation, that is the way of doing it: `Class::method()`.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at [`ContentEntityForm::form()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!ContentEntityForm.php/function/ContentEntityForm%3A%3Aform/8.2.x), the method called with `parent::form()` since [`ContentEntityForm`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21ContentEntityForm.php/class/ContentEntityForm/8.2.x) is the parent class, you will notice what exactly it is doing.

```
  $form = parent::form($form, $form_state);
  // Content entity forms do not use the parent's #after_build callback
  // because they only need to rebuild the entity in the validation and the
  // submit handler because Field API uses its own #after_build callback for
  // its widgets.
  unset($form['#after_build']);

  $this->getFormDisplay($form_state)->buildForm($this->entity, $form, $form_state);
  // Allow modules to act before and after form language is updated.
  $form['#entity_builders']['update_form_langcode'] = [$this, 'updateFormLangcode'];
  return $form;
```

It doesn't significantly change the form, so it is expected the form doesn't apparently change, or it is rendered the same if you don't call `parent::form()`, but (as the comment says), it allows modules to act when the form language is updated. You could not see anything different, but you are actually avoiding modules can do anything when the form language is changed.